PyQgis: filledMarkerSymbolLayer data defined properties not transferred to marker symbol
No pressing need here - I am mostly trying to determine what symbology can and can't
be modified in PyQgis as opposed to the QGis GUI.  In this particular case, filled
marker symbols.
Qgs.filledMarkerSymbolLayer (or it's ultimate base Qgs.SymbolLayer) has methods
setFillColor() and SetStrokeColor() that have no effect on filled marker symbols.  The
docs state clearly that for setFillColor()
This property is not supported by all symbol layer types, only those with a fill component.
and for setStrokeColor()
This property is not supported by all symbol layer types, only those with a stroke component.
But in the QGis GUI you can set both a fill color and a stroke color, so there is obviously a fill component to the symbol.
In the GUI you can specify a fill type (solid, cross, etc.).  There is no explicit
method to setStyle() or setFillStyle() that I could find, but there is a QgsSymbol.Property
"FillStyle" (Fill style (eg solid, dots)) that seems like it would do the trick (although I
do not see "dots" in the GUI selection box).  When I set the data defined property to "cross"
using
property=QgsProperty()
property.setStaticValue("cross")
filledMarkerSymbolLayer = layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0)
filledMarkerSymbolLayer.setDataDefinedProperty(filledMarkerSymbolLayer.Property['FillStyle'], property)

and list the filledMarkerSymbolLayer data defined properties I see
Symbol layer data defined properties:
1 [12 ]
12 FillStyle cross
However, it has no effect on the filled marker symbols, and when I go to the GUI and look at the
data defined override toggle it tells me "Current definition (): undefined" in spite of what I saw
when I listed the data defined properties above.  The same is true for several other properties, but
not for "Name" which, when set to "diamond" or "square" does override the GUI setting.
[As an aside, all of this stuff works splendidly with a polygon layer as it should.]
Why are certain properties that should apply to a symbol layer type that obviously has a fill component that can be implemented in the GUI not sticking when applied through established methods (setFillColor(), etc.) or data defined overrides?

Per the documentation, QgsFilledMarkerSymbolLayer consists "of a shape which is rendered using a QgsFillSymbol. This allows the symbol to support advanced styling of the interior and stroke of the shape."
In other words, the symbol layer consists of 1) a shape, and 2) a QgsFillSymbol that is used to render the shape. The QgsFillSymbol is accessed through the subSymbol property of the QgsFilledMarkerSymbolLayer. In turn, it can have whatever symbol layers it needs to render the QgsFilledMarkerSymbolLayer's shape. By default, it is created with a single QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer, which has the basic stroke and fill properties you are looking for, the same way it does if it is used to render a polygon geometry.

Thank you, couteau. Creating a new QgsFillSymbol and using
layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0).setSubSymbol(newSymbol)
did exactly as advertised. Unfortunately, since I posted as a guest, I don't seem to be able to mark the answer as correct or award points.  Sorry.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please follow instructions at https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your two accounts.
